# Why is an array with a single number in it considered a number?

Tags: javascript

While working on an `isNumeric` function I found this edge case:

`[5]` is considered a number, can be used with numerical operators like  `+`, `-`,`/` etc and gives `5` when given to `parseFloat`.

Why does JavaScript convert a single value array to a number?

For example

```js
const x = [10];
console.log(x - 5, typeof x);
```

gives

```
5 object
```

Comment: A tiny thing to note: *"can be used with numerical operators like  `+`"* - This is correct, but the result of `[10]+5` wouldn't be `15`, it would be `"105"`.  As CertainPerformance explains below, the array is converted to a comma-separated **string** before the operation is performed, and where the `-` operator will coerce the surrounding expressions to numbers, the `+` operator [does not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()). (e.g., `"10" + 5 === "105"`)

Comment: @TylerRoper: I find it curious (and IMHO unfortunate) that `"use strict"` didn't clean up more of that kind of nonsense.  Some JavaScript implementations manage to eke amazing levels of performance out of the language, but many aspects of the language are mind-bogglingly horrible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `-` operator attempts to coerce its surrounding expressions to numbers. `[5]`, when converted to a primitive (joining all elements by `,`), evaluates to `'5'`, which can be clearly converted to a number without issue.

See the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression - MultiplicativeExpression
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(lval).
> 4. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 5. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 6. ReturnIfAbrupt(rval).
> 7. **Let lnum be ToNumber(lval).**
> 8. ReturnIfAbrupt(lnum).
> 9. Let rnum be ToNumber(rval).
> 10. ReturnIfAbrupt(rnum).
> 11. Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to lnum and rnum. See the note below 12.7.5.

Where `ToNumber` [does](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber), in the case of an object:

> 1. Let primValue be ToPrimitive(argument, hint Number).
> 2. Return ToNumber(primValue).

which leads to [ToPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive), calling `toString` on the array, which leads to [Array.prototype.toString](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.tostring), which calls `.join`.